# How to update a command-line program using Homebrew?

Tags: homebrew

`curl` is a command line tool for transferring data with URLs. It is installed on my system as version 7.51.0. According to [the tool's homepage](https://curl.haxx.se/), its current version number is 7.54.0. I'd like to update my copy of this tool to the latest version.

According to the [Releases and Downloads page](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html) of `curl`'s website, the latest version can be installed on Mac OS X using Homebrew.

How can I use Homebrew to update my copy of `curl` to the latest version? Is updating the same as installing? If so, then the answer to my question is:

```
> brew install curl
```

But is there a different way to update an already existing program?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply no. Only Apple can update programs in /usr/bin etc.

However you can make your scripts find the program from Homebrew first. You do this by making your `$PATH` have `/usr/local/bin` (which is where Homebrew puts links to the executables) earlier in the `$PATH` than OS supplied programs.

Comment: I see. And how can I use Homebrew to update a program that I have previously installed using Homebrew?

Comment: @EvanAad it's `brew upgrade FORMULA`. You can check it with `brew help`.